# Computing Partial Sums of a vector

Tags: concurrency, barrier

In G. Andrews *Foundations of Multithreaded, Parallel and Distributed Programming* we are given the following algorithm using barriers to compute the sum of all prefixes of a vector:

[image: prefix sum algorithm]

It claims that all barriers are needed to avoid interferences between processes, but I fail to see the purpose of the first barrier right after initialization. After all, the value of old[i] only depends on sum[i], which is not at the first iteration influenced by any process other than i.

Is it really needed?